# Need to increase font size of Product category TITLE (I am Using Woocommerce And Wordpress Astra Themes)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, opacity, font-size

Hi I am using astra starter theme with woocommerce
I need to **increase font size, change background colour** to transparent for both actual and hover ,for both my category and subcategory headings
Please can anyone help me.
Really appreciated

The page I need help with: https://www.annure.com/product-category/iphone-skins/
e.g.
[ The word IPHONE 11 ] .

I tried using the code on my Custom CSS and Advanced CSS of Customiser ,but it did not work.

The code is mentioned as below :

```
.product-category h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Once I  tried using h3 and then h2 as well.

I also tried this code

```
#top.archive .products .product h3 {
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `h3` element and generally your `css` selectors does not exists

**If you want to change the Iphone 11 on the left this is the correct selector to use:**

```
.product-categories li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Hi,what about changing opacity of background of font to transparent (with and without hovering on it)